# Symfony2 working with forms

Tags: forms, symfony

am a bigginer , i am confuse about how to work with symfony forms to make the following:
i have a table(entity) user,exam,exam_questions and table response that has the fields (question,reponse,user):
each user pass one or multiple exams, each exam has multiple questions, i want to make a form where there is list of questions of the given exam. bellow each question a text input for the user to write his response,

what's the correct way to do this? should i work with embeded forms or simple one ? and how should i use them?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with this symfony 2  official tutorial:

1. First Learn how Symfony 2 form works= 
    http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html
2. How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events=
    http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

   For more check out "How to customize Form Rendering" topic in cookbook of Symfony 2.

Comment: i read it but still can't find a solution to my case: because i have a triple relationship between my entities : exam exercice and answer. which means a user can answer the exercices of one or multiple exams, how can i make this with forms the documentation didn't talk about this or i couldn't figure it out,anyway i need your help plz